# How can I fade in and then set focus in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I've got this little snippet of jQuery:

```
$('#showlink').click(function(){ 
 $('#linkwindow').show('fast');
    $('#linkwindow input').focus();
}
```

How do I call the focus only after the fade has ended? Sometimes it happens slightly before and I end up with a weird rendering bug.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this, using the [callback](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/show#speedcallback) parameter.

```
$('#showlink').click(function(){  
  $('#linkwindow').show('fast', function() {
    $('#linkwindow input').focus();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You may add a callback to the `show` method:

```
$('#showlink').click(function(){ 
    $('#linkwindow').show('fast', function() {
        $('#linkwindow input').focus();
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the callback second parameter.

Something like:

```
$('#linkwindow').show('fast', function() { 
    $('#linkwindow input').focus(); 
});
```